# InAppBrowser - "phonegap plugin add" fails

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

This seems like a relatively common issue, but I can't seem to find any solution that works for my situation.

When I try to install the InAppBrowser plugin, it always fails.

These are the commands I've tried:

```
sudo phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

This results in the error `[error] Cannot read property 'install' of undefined`

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cd cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
git checkout 3.1.0
cd $MY_PHONEGAP_APP
phonegap local plugin add /.../cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

When I do the `git checkout` command, it results in the error `error: pathspec '3.1.0' did not match any file(s) known to git.` If I skip that step, I get the error `[error] Fetching plugin failed: Error: Failed to fetch package information for /.../cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

These are other things I've tried:

- Upgrading PhoneGap to its latest version
- Downgrading PhoneGap to a 3.1 version and a 3.2 version
- Creating another app and trying to install InAppBrowser on the new app.

Nothing seems to work. Help would definitely be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Turns out there's (probably) some sort of bug in the latest plugin version that's been screwing up installation. I've gone ahead and installed an older version (by adding @{version_number} at the end). This works for me:

```
sudo phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser@0.3.0
```

Comment: same issue in this moment. i currently download plugin(s) from apache repos (url like https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git). how to download precedent branches\tag from same repo? it seems that id download (using namespace) installl a non working plugin

Comment: also https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/tree/r0.3.0 won't work in `phonegap local plugin add` command

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure how to download from that repo; my knowledge of all this is pretty limited :-/

Comment: finally i've managed to let `>phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser@0.3.0` to work. don't really know why it was'nt in first place. issue came after phonegap downgrade from 3.4.x to 3.1, may be uncompleted plugin update.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to update plugman module:

`npm install -g plugman`